# How to set "text-align" to its default value (disable "text-align" inheritance)

Tags: html, css

In a specific part on my document (a novel) I have a block of text that most be centered but not its content. For this, I used:

```
<div class="center">
    <div class="inline-block">
        <p class="left">Some text</p>
        <p class="left">More text</p>
        <p class="left">Even more text</p>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
.center {
    text-align: center;
}

.inline-block {
    display: inline-block;
    width: /* sometimes I specify it, others I let the biggest paragraph do it by itself  */;
}

.left {
    text-align: left;
}
</style>
```

Overall, I am satisfied with this solution. But, as you can see, I need to use the class “.left” to avoid paragraphs to inherit the centered value of their parent div. The thing is that I don’t want to set the justification (justified/left) of my document; I want the user (or the default browser/app/epub reader/etc.) to set it instead. The problem is that if I don’t add this class “.left”, the paragraphs will inherit the centered value.

Is there a way to make this paragraphs have a “default” value (either justified or left)? ¿Can I achieve the same overall design using other elements/styles? Can I disable the inheritance for this paragraphs by any means?

I have tried things that included “transform: translateX(-50%)”, “display: table”, setting the paragraphs to “value: initial;”, mixing pseudo-classes/attribute selectors… Basically, everything I could to see if I can trick my way through. So far nothing works. Any ideas?

Comment: something like `.center p {text-align: left}` ? If you anyways want to override the `text-align : center` for all cases, why set it in the first place?

Comment: You could just center the block differently and not set text-align at all since your text align never changes. There are lots of ways to center a block, create a simplified example and we will show you

Comment: I'd think `.center p { text-align: initial }` is less obtrusive if he just wants to **cancel** the inheritance.
Edit: unset is indeed better.

Comment: The problem with `.center p {text-align: left}` is that if the app default value is justified, then this paragraphs will have another value. I want this paragraphs tho be the same as the *default*.

Comment: Might as well set `text-align: initial` on `.inline-block` or just don't set anything and center the block differently

Comment: How can I centered this box differently? Remember that I need its content to set the width of the entire box.

Comment: The class names would need fixing (which is one reason why you should name classes by their html content, not by their styling) but you could do [`.center .inline-block { display: table;  margin: 0 auto; }`](http://jsfiddle.net/2m2fuzL0/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use `initial`

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.rtl {
  direction: rtl;
}

.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: /* sometimes I specify it, others I let the biggest paragraph do it by itself  */
  ;
  border: solid;
}

.left {
  text-align: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="inline-block">
    <p class="left">Some text</p>
    <p class="left">More text</p>
    <p class="left">Even more text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<hr/>Test when direction is the otherway round...
<div class="center rtl">

  <div class="inline-block">
    <p class="left">Some text</p>
    <p class="left">More text</p>
    <p class="left">Even more text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial

> The **`initial`** CSS keyword applies the initial value of a property to an element. It can be applied to any CSS property, including the CSS shorthand all.

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
.inline-block p {
    text-align: initial;
}
```

```css
.center {
    text-align: center;
}

.inline-block p {
    text-align: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">Center
    <div class="inline-block">
        <p class="left">Some text</p>
        <p class="left">More text</p>
        <p class="left">Even more text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```